# Factor with 4 levels False, FALSE, True, TRUE but need just 2 levels

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataframe set as factor with 4 levels

```
False, FALSE, True, TRUE
```

I need to reduce to 2 levels

```
FALSE, TRUE
```

I have done this (which works fine) but is there a better way:

```
df$col1 <- as.character(df$col1)    # change the factor to chr
df$col1 <- toupper (df$col1)        # Ensure all are uppercase
df$col1 <- as.factor(df$col1)       # change back
```

Comment: you can also use `gsub`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use `as.logical`:

```
d <- c("False", "FALSE", "True", "TRUE")
factor(as.logical(d))
# [1] FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

From `?as.logical`:

> Character strings `c("T", "TRUE", "True", "true")` are regarded as true,
>   `c("F", "FALSE", "False", "false")` as false, and all others as
>   `NA`.